# I want to give notification to the user (mobile application) when the if block is execute. this code doesn't work, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

```
if (200 <= intId && intId <= 250) {//if there is some Thondering give a alert

                    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setTicker("Tickertittle")
                            .setContentTitle("ELEKTRA WEATHER ALERT")
                            .setContentText("TURN OFF the multi plug for lighting safety")
                            .setContentIntent();

                       noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                       NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                       nm.notify(0,noti);

                }
```

Comment: You are calling `setContentIntent()` with no PendingIntent parameter. You should at least create a *dummy* Intent/PendingIntent so that this call won't fail. I will create an answer for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to have an Intent for the Notification, you should create a *dummy* one

```
PendingIntent dummyIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
   getApplicationContext(),
   0,
   new Intent(),
   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and then call `setContentIntent(dummyIntent)`